# Is a highly acidic/base fast-acting glue possible?

Tags: warfare, chemistry, religion

A request for the Department of Unconventional Cleansing and Annihilation: The Senatorium has decided that a fast acting glue needs to be created which burns its victims as they are trapped in the glue, making it easier for our Propaganda Crews to film their agony and teach Our Adversaries a Lesson.

Some of the nay sayers of the Senatorium have made claims that this may not be possible, these traitors have been immediately Executed for the Greater Good. Their complaint was that a glue is a bonding agent and any burning by an acidic or base material* may interfere with the bonding, forcing our Propaganda Crews to run after the heretical traitors in field conditions.

The question is as follows. After answering properly if a glue can simultaneously immobilize the traitorous heretic and burn them to death will you:

1: be executed for not providing us with the answers we seek like the traitor you are. You wasted valuable resources provided by the Grace of Our Glorious God-Regent, in debt we are to His Name, and shalt die a Painful and Public death as is the fate of all who stand in Our Way.

2: get to live another day, having paid your Debt to His Holiness for that day despite your heretical knowledge of the "sciences".

3: prove the tools are worthy and operational as you Cleanse Our Enemies and Earn your **Citizenship**°! Glory to you as you smite Our Enemies in Service to us all!

*we had like, a **proper** education such as Saluting the Flag, Reciting Our Glorious History, Proper Interpretation of all Sermons and singing Our Unified Anthem. We dont know the "sciency" name for stuff.

°would you like to know **more**? Join the army of our Glorious Democratic Free Federation Of Super Earth! Crush the Arachidea beneath Our Armored Boot! Burn the Unbeliever and the Heretic! Smite the Cult of Telekinetic Lasersword Wizards! Evicerate the vile Xenos! **Citizenship** guaranteed!

Comment: How would the glue come in contact with its victims? Would it be fired on them, in the form of shells or grenades, or would there be some kind of traps or mines?

Comment: @InTheAbsenceOfFear quit stalling! You are the one with heretical knowledge! You find out how to best use it! Try to get it in as many weapons as possible!

Comment: plaster of paris can cause severe burns and most two-part epoxies are exothermic. I recall reading about n approx a 1-inch pour (smaller than a hockey puck) of epoxy without temperature control hit about 400F

Comment: @Yorik Your comment made me think of quickset dry mix cement.

Answer (score 3):

## Acids changes things

*I couldn't find confirmation on the subject, so please leave a comment with corrections if needed.*

Acids have several forms, but as far as I know they work more or less in the same way. They have an abundance or a lack of something, making them easily react with other substances. A reaction means that each of the substances get altered and/or merged into a single or multiple different substances.

If we establish that an acid changes from one form to another when in contact with other substances, it can be that one of the by-products is something similar to glue. An alternative is that it doesn't make glue, but simply fuses things together during the transition, not unlike welding things together (though with acid there will be different molecules after the fact).

Looking around on the PH scale I couldn't find any directly where this seems to be the case, but with a story we can make fictional ones.

The acid can:

1. Go into a reaction of which a resulting product hardens on the body, inert to further acid and leaving the victim trapped.
2. Go onto a reaction which fuses with the existing organics. This hardens, leaving the victim trapped.
3. Goes into an exothermic reaction, basically supplying the oxygen while an oxidation reaction is under way. The outside layer if the acid simply loses it's oxygen in a reaction with the air (nitrogen?), hardening around the victim. Victim is trapped with 'active' acid inside a hardened shell.

I think these options are a good start for the creation of further creative acids, which I'll leave to other people. The gist is that the acid has a reaction and at least one of the results is binding.

As a side note: Frankly I never see the reason why things need to be so horrific if we can reach the same results with 1% of the horror.

Comment: While I personally do not understand it, I've come to the conclusion that there is a market for horror. Are you old enough to remember the golden age of cannibal movies and zombie movies (mid to late 1970's to early 1980's)?

Comment: Until your colleagues come with a better answer, you may live. For now. (And the horror will be toned down for the actual story)

Comment: This would be entirely dependent on what the acid is reacting *with*.  Which, might actually be even better.  An acid that becomes sticky when reacting with biological compounds but is otherwise not sounds even more horrifying.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not tagged this hard-science, I'm going to assume handwaving is allowed, at least to some extent.

A two-component system, consisting of an acid and a rapid-acting substance, impervious to the acid, that forms a container, rather than a glue. I'm thinking a gas that quickly solidifies into [Polyvinylidene fluoride (PVDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyvinylidene_fluoride), similarly to how [Amber](https://fringe.fandom.com/wiki/Amber) in the TV-series [Fringe](https://fringe.fandom.com/wiki/FringeWiki) solidifies into an amber like shell. PVDF is resistant to [Hydrofluoric Acid (HF)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK441829/), which is a powerful inorganic acid that causes severe burns as well as acute respitory symptoms among other nasty things.

For deployment, I'd consider traps that when stepped on release the gaseous PVDF, that encases the feet and lower legs as it solidifies, followed by highly concentrated HF, that is sprayed upward around the victim, in a undulating movement so as to soak the whole body of the victim. The traps would, of course, need large enough containers to hold enough HF to kill the victim, and The Sanatorium personel documenting it would have to be far enough away not to be affected by the vapors, or wear protective suits.

This system should also be possible to use for scheduled executions. A scaffold behind a shield of transparent PVDF, onto which the heretics are forced, resulting in the activation of the system, and the crowd on the other side of the shield goes wild.

Comment: Get working on a prototype! You have earned your right to live! For now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I should provide an answer - on one side there is a option to figth with Xenos(like this prospect very much), on the other hand voluntarely figth with trees(do not like it that much)

### To raise biohazard awareness, and to respect OSHA and other safety regulations

Looking for strong acid may be not the thing you actually need, look at hydrogen fluoride burns pictures - quite nasty stuff. And it more nasty in its action than it looks, because it permiates skin, flesh and bones, not an expert, but heard that and did some ligth research on the topic - nasty stuff. It does not have an immediate effect, a person may not notice the problem, but it already happened quite deep in progress.

So some compaund which like foam adhesive expands creates shell hardens and creates bubbles with that FH probably possible, or when it is in solution in  water(or other solvents) I guess it will work similarly and considering it won't chew trough everything like acid from aliens movie it can be mixed with a lot of stuff without reacting with it (dentists use it as gel stuff, as an example - this acid is weird).

So you look not for the strong acid, but for a stuff which wrecks cells with selective reactions with Na, K, Ca (it is my guess what happens there, may be wrong and considering salts formed more processes may happen here as well) which makes cells incapable to operate and die. It a weak acid(on acid scale), but it has some weird properties, due set of reasons.

### PS

Can't comment so

- *... What point would there be in a slow acting acid ...*

Seems you propaganda department is still too fresh, you figured how to use glue to fix an object in a position/pose, but didn't figure out the power of 240x timelapse. A touch of cgi as well for a better seemless transition between frames, and it golden prop material - seeing = believing

Comment: I DO NOT UNDERSTAND YOUR ANSWER! What is OSHA? We have the bureau of acceptable losses! What point would there be in a slow acting acid? We need a wicked witch in the west from our (very selective) propaganda reels! Not a dentist!

Answer (score 0):

### Dry mix cement

Quickset dry mix cement has pH 13 or 14, gets extremely hot, and sets within minutes. Available with a wide range of setting times. 10 - 20 dollars for 20 kg.

There are various wet mix cements that set a little slower without getting quite as hot but still have pH 13/14.